# Iterating through Drupal Views inside my template using foreach

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to access a Drupal View through my template and want to iterate through it's results to show data. Something simple, like:

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
    echo $field['name_of_the_field'];
}
```

So i can have full control of my view display inside my teplate. And, of course, being easier to build my template in Drupal. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a views template and then access what you need through that.

Go to the views, and under the 'Basic Settings' section.  Click on the 'Theme: information' link.

Then, you'll see a list possible template links.

[image]

Click on one of those links and you'll see textarea  with the template.  Copy the template to a file with the same name as the link name and put it in your themes folder.

[image]

Anyway, once you have the proper template, you'll see what object you can iterate over.